# Configuring svn client on mac for eclipse for android development

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I am trying to configure Subclipse svn for eclipse on mac. I have installed Eclipse Indigo, Subclipse (latest) and SVNKIT 1.7 When I try to add respository than I receive following error

```
Error Validating location: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn
E175002: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
```

The solution i found [here](http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SVNKIT-176) and it says that to run following command

```
-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols="SSLv3"
```

but I dont know how and where to run this command. Can anybody help? Or if u think there is some other solution to the problem than let me know.

Answer (score 3):

1.- Go to eclipse folder.
2.- execute this command:  **./eclipse -vmargs -Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols="SSLv3"**
3.- that's all!   now, if you want, so you create a script to launch eclipse

NOTE:  My english is very bad, sorry, but im learning it :D

Answer (score 2):

Add it to your eclipse.ini, that's where settings like that should go. Unless you really want to add it only to a shortcut/script that runs it as a cli parameter (what antraxa posted).

Comment: Make sure you omit the quotes around **SSLv3**, or you will get an (cryptic) error.